# How to remove something from list just in object, not in the DB in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a list of objects and I want to get whole list from db. After some lines of code I want to delete some objects from the list, but not from the DB.
My code something like:

```
MyObject object = findById(id);
List list = object.getList();
list.removeIf(element -> /*a condition/); //I don't want to delete it from DB

/*Some actions that affect on DB*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reflect you changed onto the DB, you have to detach the object first

```
em.detach(object);
```